# Updating DOM for everyone when database changes - MongoDB, Ajax, Express,React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm making an application where when user submits a form, i want DOM to be updated for everyone on that page, realtime, without refreshing the page.

I have tried doing that with Socket.IO, and it kinda works, but the problem is that it only works if someone is already on that page and i don't need that functionality, i need that when users SUBMITS a form, view is not updated only for existing connection but also when someone loads the page first time and requests were already done.

So, i decided to create a database and check for changes and it works as expected

basically the work flow of the app is this

user submits form => fetch function that checks database for changes is fired => it finds new database entry => updates React state => change is sent to the view

But the problem is that if i do the updating of dom this way, i'm afraid i may be overloading the server unnecessary. I Checked, and every new open instance of
"http://localhost:3000/seek" checks to see if database is changed and so, if i had 1000 users on my web app that would be 1000 requests every second :o

Maybe i should combine both socket.io and database and use that approach for updating dom realtime?

**Seek.js (Server Side)**

```
router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    // Processes form
    // Saving to database
    // Sending response
});

router.get('/:fetch', (req,res,next) => {
    if(req.params.fetch === 'fetch'){
        Seek.find(function(err,games){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log('FETCHED')
            res.status(200).send({games});
        })
    }else{
        next();
    }
});
```

**seekDiv.jsx**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { games:[] };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchGames()
  }

  fetchGames(){
     fetch('http://www.localhost:3000/seek/fetch')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {this.setState({games: data.games})})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval( () => this.fetchGames(), 1000)
  }

  render() {
    var games = this.state.games;
    let zero;

    if(games.length === 0){
        zero = ''
    }else{
        zero = games.map(x => <div>{x.userAlias}</div>)
    }
    return(
    <div>
       {zero}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm hoping that i presented my problem clear enough but in case i didn't this is the functionality i want

users submits form => the DOM is updated for EVERY user without refresh containing that form data and is also there until it's manually removed.

Any help on how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is that if i do the updating of dom this way, i'm afraid i may be overloading the server unnecessary. I Checked, and every new open instance of "http://localhost:3000/seek" checks to see if database is changed and so, if i had 1000 users on my web app that would be 1000 requests every second :o

Yeah - that is a problem. Conceptually, you need to make this a "push" not "pull" system.

Rather than having every client constantly ask the server if there are updates, you simply need to leave a socket connection open to every page (very low resource use) and on your server, after receiving a new form/post - you then push to every connected client the update.

The [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) have a good example of how to do this in the "broadcast" section. It's for chat messages, but it works the same way for your forms.

You'll want to minimize the data you send to every client to the bare minimum needed. So if you record any additional data (say, a timestamp of when the new post was added) unless you are displaying or using that data on the front end, you wouldn't want to send it to all of the listening client.

You'll want your front end to be monitoring for incoming updates, and when it does, use react to update the DOM accordingly.